# Why won't the font-set on div-tag work？

Tags: html, css, jsp

```
<div style="margin:0px auto;padding-top:20px;width:1000px;font-size :90pt;!important;" id="showBroadcastContent">
    <ul><strong>Loading Broadcasts...</strong></ul>
</div>
```

[image: this is firebug shows]

In the picture above, the font displayed comes from fistyle.css. However, I think the div-tag setting has more priority.

How can I have the div show my font style?

Comment: Please avoid inline styling..its not good you can add it `#showBroadcastContent { font-size: 90pt !important; }`

Comment: I set it ,but  still coverd by fistyle.css

Comment: can you share your site url

Answer (score 0):

Wrong type `font-size :90pt;!important;`

It should be `font-size :90pt !important;`

Answer (score 0):

YOu change code:

```
font-size :90pt;!important;
```

To

```
font-size :90pt!important;
```

it balances commas

Answer (score 0):

just check with this on firebug.. and when you work with css avoid camel case letters

```css
#showBroadcastContent {
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-top:20px;
    width:1000px;
    font-size :90pt!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="showBroadcastContent">
   <ul><strong>Loading Broadcasts...</strong></ul>
</div>
```